# IO Port Address RJ11

Tags: io

I've 2 PCs running Ubuntu. The PCs are from different vendors. They have IO port interface via RJ11 connector. They are used for accessing the cash drawer. On one PC, I'm able to access the cash drawer at 0x48C. But the same does not work on the other PC. I do not have the spec for both cash drawer and the PC.

I would like to know how can I get the IO port address to access the cash drawer. I've tried cat /proc/ioports, but not able to find it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Nara

Comment: I would try dmesg. if not, then setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0123456789] and similar commands might help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I already tried dmesg. Was not able to see any message when I plug in or unplug the cable.

Comment: The following is the O/P from setserial command on the system in which the I'm facing the problem: 

sudo setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0123456789]
[sudo] password for t2s: 
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 5
/dev/ttyS3, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 10
/dev/ttyS4, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02f0, IRQ: 5

Comment: The serial port is not plug and play, you will need to check the input on different adreses. I would check also BIOS settings which is the address of your serial port.

Comment: I've checked the BIOS and it matches the setserial O/P. Any other command I can check. ?

Comment: Try:     sudo cat /proc/tty/driver/serial